# How to disable "Add to Cart" and Quantity button if product is out of Stock?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.4, swatches

I want to disable **add to cart and qty option** if product is **out of stock**, but i also want to show price and swatches of the products and the swatches should be clickable and price should be changeable according to swatches
I also want to show **"add to cart and qnty option"** but they should not be clickable[image]

in this case when product is out of stock, all options are not visible, swatches and price is not accessible , i want that price and swatches should be accessible and visible
but quantity and add to cart option should be disable. Any idea how to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/304604/how-to-hide-add-to-cart-button-for-particular-products-on-all-page-in-magento-2

Comment: it doest give the required output, button is not visibale when applied this solution, i want to show button but the action should not be performed when on click if product is out of stock

Answer (score 0):

All that if you want is not to show the "Add to cart" button. You will be in need to remove the block responsible for adding that on details page.

Have a look at this file:

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml
```

The block adding "Add to cart" is:

```
name="product.info.addtocart"
```

** Do not make change in vendor you need to override the same in your theme and remove that block.

If you do not want to remove it you can have a look at:

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml
```

Again do not change in vendor override this file and you can apply condition/change as per yours need.

But with this changes will only be applicable on product view page. In order to perform customization on list view, have a look at this file:

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml
```

If stock reaches "0" and if from backend you have set not to display out of stock products then ideally it should not display.
You can try by reindexing:

```
php bin/magento i:rei
```

for reference: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/272688/92166